# How do I give a user only access to a subfolder in my svn-repository?

Tags: svn, debian, apache2, webdav

I have an existing subversion repository with many sub-folders in it. A new person joined my team and I want to give them access to the Subversion repository, but not at all. They should get access only to one of the folders in Subversion repository. So, how do I give a user only access to a sub-folder in a Subversion repository?

My setup: Debian, Apache2, DAV, SVN

Comment: Briefly: What you need is HTTP authentication (e.g. BASIC, via `AuthType Basic`) and then limit the access to specific URL via `<Location /svn/private/project> Require group admin </Location>`

Answer (score 1):

Permissions on specific paths of SVN repositories can be provided by creating an access file. More details can be found by reading the [SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/). Here is a sample:

```
[gui:/] 
@admin = rw
john = rw
#
[logic:/]
@admin = rw
jack = rw
john = r
ali = rw
```